# Patch function can’t accept global variable

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a form that allows users to edit fields and buttons beside each field to “Submit” changes. The “Submit” button opens “pop up” window to confirm if a user wants to change a field. I have a “Proceed” button that I want to execute the Patch but can’t seem to figure out how to pass the column name and value that the user changed.

I tried storing my Patch method in a global named varPassPatch like the following, Set(varPassPatch, “Patch({columnName : newValue})”) then pass this variable into the OnSelect property of Proceed button but it doesn’t seem to be executing.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not pretty but I was able to pass variables to the Switch function of the OnSelect property that would then choose which patch function to executr based on the passed variables.